# AM PM is not considered while local sorting of date extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime, extjs

I am getting a problem while doing the local sort for my grid,

here the date is sorted on the basis of hours and min **but not considerig the AM/PM part**

most probably its taking string sort not the date sort.. how to make it date sort-able..

it should come in descending order (latest first, oldest last) like:

19-Dec-2013 10:43:54 PM (UTC +5:30)

19-Dec-2013 3:43:54 PM (UTC +5:30)

19-Dec-2013 7:03:28 AM (UTC +5:30)

but its coming in this order

19-Dec-2013 10:43:54 PM (UTC +5:30)

19-Dec-2013 7:03:28 AM (UTC +5:30)

19-Dec-2013 3:43:54 PM (UTC +5:30)

i am doing it like:

```
fields:{ name:'PD', mapping:'@PD', dateFormat: 'c', type: 'date'},
```

`sortInfo: {
            field: 'PD',
            direction: 'DESC'
        },
remoteSort: false,`

sortable:true for this column.

what could be the possible error or what i am missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the sort type of a field in a store by setting the `sortType` config option. Using your example:

```
fields: {
    name: 'PD',
    mapping: '@PD',
    dateFormat: 'c',
    type: 'date',
    sortType: 'asDate'
},
```

I haven't used the `asDate` sort type, but hopefully that will work for you. You can find a list of the predefined sort types at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes.

You can also set the `sortType` config equal to a function, to define a custom sort type. Here is the example found in the docs at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field:

```
sortType: function(value) {
    switch (value.toLowerCase()) // native toLowerCase():
    {
        case 'first': return 1;
        case 'second': return 2;
        default: return 3;
   }
}
```